# Python: Checking file existence, while avoiding race conditions, without opening file

Tags: security, python-3.x, race-condition, large-files, file-exists

Is there a means to check if a file exists, avoiding any potential race conditions, while not reading the file into memory?

I've seen examples using try/catch to avoid race conditions, but they all read the file into memory with something like:

```
with open filename as file
```

I have a large file (roughly 100mb) that I need to check the existence of, but for security's sake, would like to avoid creating a race condition while checking. Reading the entire file into memory is impractical. What am I not thinking of?

I'm new, be gentle.

Comment: The classic os.path.exists ? Anyway, try/catch and with open don't read the file, just give you a handle or FileNotFoundError

Comment: could you clarify what race condition you're trying to avoid?  The main reason with the idiom you mentioned to to read the file and avoid a race condition between when os.path.exists() returns true and your open would fail because someone was deleting the file

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that "with open" reads the entire file into memory before, now I realize that I was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The *entire purpose* of race condition avoidance is *strictly* so that the file being opened is the file that was checked for. Trying to have one without the other is a non sequitur.

Also, `open()` doesn't read the file into memory, so that part of the question doesn't even make sense to begin with.

Comment: I was under the impression that open() reads files entirely into memory which was my issue. You're saying that it doesn't though, which means that I can use the try/catch methods I've seen without fear of 100mb of RAM being eaten. That was what I meant anyway. Thanks for clarifying!